# How to add data-column with insertCell()?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my problem:
I have a table in html with parameters 'data-column' in my `<td>` elements like this:

```
<td class="column100 column1" data-column="column1">Total</td>
<td class="column100 column2" data-column="column2">--</td>
```

With a Javascript function, I want to add new row and columns, It's work, but the element 'data-column="columnX"' is not added and I don't know how to add it?
This is a part of my Javascript function.

```
var a = x.insertCell(0);
var b = x.insertCell(1);
a.className = 'column100 column1';
b.className = 'column100 column2';
```

The result is:

```
<td class="column100 column1">Mois 0</td>
<td class="column100 column2">--</td>
```

But I need to add the 'data-column'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setAttribute`

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x");
var a = x.insertCell(0);
a.className = 'column100 column1';
a.setAttribute("data-column", "column1");
a.innerText = x.innerHTML;
```

```html
<table><tr id="x"></tr></table>
```